# how to disable validation Webpart when it is in edit mode

Tags: sharepoint-server

Currently I have a WebPart that contains asp.net validations, but the problem is when I try save the page not is posbile why the page have validations pending correction.

**Anyone know how I can fix this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is Answer

```
if (WebPartManager.DisplayMode != WebPartManager.BrowseDisplayMode)
{
    foreach (var validator in Controls)
    {
        if (validator is BaseValidator)
        {
            ((BaseValidator)validator).Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/58663/22045